# How to obtain byte array via sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream instance?

Tags: java, spring

I am using DefaultPropertiesPersister to override properties. My configuration is like this.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
      <list>
          <value>classpath:/META-INF/properties/common.properties</value>
          <value>classpath:/META-INF/properties/${spring.profiles.active}.properties</value>
          <value>classpath:/META-INF/properties/${spring.profiles.active}.passwords</value>
          <value>classpath:/META-INF/properties/local.properties</value>
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="propertiesPersister">
        <bean class="com.freecharge.ums.server.service.MyPropertyPersister" />
    </property>        
</bean>
```

Now after extending DefaultPropertiesPersister, i override the method:

```
load(Properties props, InputStream is)
```

Now after launching the jar, the InputStream I'm getting is of the type `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream`. When I try to convert it to `byte[]` using `IOUtils.toByteArray(is)`, I get nothing.

When I run the same thing via a `main` method, I get through because the stream i get is `java.io.BufferedInputStream` and it is able to convert it into byte array.

Did a lot of research, but couldn’t get through with this. thanks in advance.

load method in `MyPropertyPersister` class is implemented as follows:

```
@Override
public void load(Properties props, InputStream is) throws IOException {
    Tika tika = new Tika();
    String type = tika.detect(is);
    if (!type.equals("text/plain")) {
        try {
            byte[] cipherText = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            ByteBuffer cipherTextBlob = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipherText);
            logger.info("cipherTextBlob: " + cipherTextBlob);
            DecryptRequest decryptReq = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(cipherTextBlob);
            awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_KMS_KEY, AWS_KMS_SECRET);
            amazonKMSClient = new AWSKMSClient(awsCredentials).withRegion(...some region...);
            DecryptResult decryptResult = amazonKMSClient.decrypt(decryptReq);
            String fileContents = new String(decryptResult.getPlaintext().array());

            props.load(new StringReader(fileContents));                

            logger.info("props: " + props);
            super.load(props, is);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("e: ", e);
        }            
    } else {
        super.load(props, is);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope my question is clear, if not PLEASE comment here. will try to clarify more.

Comment: Can you show the code in MyPropertyPersister.load(Properties props, InputStream is)

Comment: thanks for replying, have edited the method in question.